# Перенос элементы списка

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, список

```css
#mainmenu
{
    border: 1px solid black;
    widtd: 400px;
}
#mainmenu ul li
{
    list-style-type: none;
    display: inline;
    padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div id="mainmenu">
    <ul>
        <li>1</li><li>1</li><li>1</li><li>1</li><li>1</li><li>1</li><li>1</li><li>1</li><li>1</li><li>1</li><li>1</li><li>1</li><li>1</li><li>1</li><li>1</li><li>1</li><li>1</li><li>1</li><li>1</li><li>1</li><li>1</li><li>1</li><li>1</li><li>1</li><li>1</li><li>1</li><li>1</li><li>1</li><li>1</li><li>1</li><li>1</li><li>1</li><li>1</li><li>1</li><li>1</li><li>1</li><li>1</li><li>1</li><li>1</li><li>1</li><li>1</li><li>1</li><li>1</li><li>1</li><li>1</li><li>1</li><li>1</li><li>1</li><li>1</li><li>1</li><li>1</li><li>1</li><li>1</li><li>1</li><li>1</li><li>1</li><li>1</li><li>1</li><li>1</li><li>1</li><li>1</li><li>1</li><li>1</li><li>1</li><li>1</li><li>1</li><li>1</li><li>1</li><li>1</li><li>1</li><li>1</li><li>1</li>
    </ul>    
</div>
```

**Вопрос**

Почему на странице отображается данная строка без переноса?

**Ожидание**

Элементы списка должны переноситься на другую строку

Comment: длинные беспробельные слова не переносятся, видимо inline-овский список считается длинным беспробельным словом, но это всего лиш предположение

Answer (score 1):

Потому что у вас стоит display: inline;

Comment: хорошо, тогда как сделать так, чтобы список был в строчку и при этом переносился?

Comment: Вы же противоречите себе. Вам нужно списком или в строчку? Как понять переносился?

Comment: И что за свойство widtd? width правильно

Comment: Вопрос уже решен, Spectre оказался прав, надо было просто список разбить на части

Answer (score 0):

### Ответ

@Spectre дал верный ответ в комментарии к вопросу.

> Длинные беспробельные слова не переносятся, видимо inline-овский
>   список считается длинным беспробельным словом.

### Первоначальный вариант

```
<div id="mainmenu">
    <ul>
        <li>1</li><li>1</li><li>1</li><li>1</li><li>1</li><li>1</li><li>1</li><li>1</li><li>1</li><li>1</li><li>1</li><li>1</li><li>1</li><li>1</li><li>1</li><li>1</li><li>1</li><li>1</li><li>1</li><li>1</li><li>1</li><li>1</li><li>1</li><li>1</li><li>1</li><li>1</li><li>1</li><li>1</li><li>1</li><li>1</li><li>1</li><li>1</li><li>1</li><li>1</li><li>1</li><li>1</li><li>1</li><li>1</li><li>1</li><li>1</li><li>1</li><li>1</li><li>1</li><li>1</li><li>1</li><li>1</li><li>1</li><li>1</li><li>1</li><li>1</li><li>1</li><li>1</li><li>1</li><li>1</li><li>1</li><li>1</li><li>1</li><li>1</li><li>1</li><li>1</li><li>1</li><li>1</li><li>1</li><li>1</li><li>1</li><li>1</li><li>1</li><li>1</li><li>1</li><li>1</li><li>1</li><li>1</li>
    </ul>    
</div>
```

### Правильный вариант

```
<div id="mainmenu">
    <ul>
        <li>1</li> <li>1</li> <li>1</li> <li>1</li> <li>1</li> <li>1</li> <li>1</li><li>1</li> <li>1</li> <li>1</li> <li>1</li> <li>1</li> <li>1</li> <li>1</li> <li>1</li><li>1</li> <li>1</li> <li>1</li> <li>1</li> <li>1</li> <li>1</li> <li>1</li> <li>1</li><li>1</li> <li>1</li> <li>1</li> <li>1</li> <li>1</li> <li>1</li> <li>1</li> <li>1</li><li>1</li> <li>1</li> <li>1</li> <li>1</li> <li>1</li> <li>1</li> <li>1</li> <li>1</li><li>1</li> <li>1</li> <li>1</li> <li>1</li> <li>1</li> <li>1</li> <li>1</li> <li>1</li><li>1</li> <li>1</li> <li>1</li> <li>1</li> <li>1</li> <li>1</li> <li>1</li> <li>1</li><li>1</li> <li>1</li> <li>1</li> <li>1</li> <li>1</li> <li>1</li> <li>1</li> <li>1</li><li>1</li> <li>1</li> <li>1</li> <li>1</li> <li>1</li> <li>1</li> <li>1</li> <li>1</li><li>1</li>
    </ul>    
</div>
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, сделайте ваши примеры воспроизводимыми

Comment: @Vlad Spirin, сейчас нет возможности. Я создал отдельный вопрос для решения проблемы